# Negation of instanceof gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these two statements? They give different output (in google chrome console).

```
function Test() {
    if (this instanceof Test) {

    } else {
        return new Test();
    }
}
x = Test();
```

*Test {}*

```
function Test() {
    if (!this instanceof Test) {
        return new Test();
    }
}
x = Test();
```

*undefined*

Mind = boggled

Comment: Well, `!this` (`false`) is not an `instanceof Test`, so the `return new Test()` isn't evaluated. Try instead with `if (!(this instanceof Test)) {`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `!` has a higher precedence than `instanceof`. Try putting `()` around `this instanceof Test`

Comment: As a reference to precedence: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the `!` evaluates before the `instanceof`, so it's being treated as:

```
if ((!this) instanceof Test) { ... }
```

And, whether `!this` is `true` or `false`, neither value is an `instanceof Test`, preventing the `new Test()` from being returned.

Adding a grouping will force the desired order for "*not an instance*:"

```
if (!(this instanceof Test)) { ... }
```